# JSONP cross-domain call returns html

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I want to ajax cross domain site to take some data from it. I successfully do it with:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     data: { internal:internal, item:item },
     success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
     }
});
```

But the response is not json, it is html, I can see it in response window in browser, but cant echo it to screen.

Can you help me?

Comment: If you're getting HTML, you're not going to a JSONP API.

Comment: but i can see the response in my browser - no way to print it to screen ?

Comment: The response to a JSONP request is required to be a Javascript function call, not HTML. It gets loaded into a `<script>` element and executed. If it's HTML, this won't work.

Comment: *"no way to print it to screen"* correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in returns html, I referred to the page via php, parsed what I need and returned needed info